# creating multiple screens in one activity

Tags: android, slideshow

I am developing a small application, where I want to show multiple screens, user can go through them by sliding finger right/left.
An example of this is what you see in lots of games with multiple levels, where one screen shows levels from 1 to 15, next will show 16 to 30, etc.
I don't think i need to create activities for each screen, do I?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). With the ViewPager you will want to associate an adapter, and in the adapter you can place Fragments which are lightweight Activities. You are right in that you don't need to create full fledged Activities for each screen. Also look into the [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), which allows you to manage multiple views in a single Activity and automatically handles navigation between them from you.

Keep in mind, this class is found in the [v4 support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), so it'll only work on Android API Level 4 and up (Android 1.6, Donut, which has a market share around a [tenth of a percent](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)) and that you'll need to include the v4 support library as a dependency in your application.

Comment: Exactly. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging for some sample code from google about using ViewPager.